# Angular 4 with angular-cli - doesn't find 3rd party provider with AOT

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot, toastr

I am building a small Angular 4 app with angular-cli 1.2.6. Everything works fine during development and it builds successfully with `ng build --dist`. But on run time, one of the 3rd party vendors called `toastr` which I use as a service is not found - when injected it is `undefined`. Here is how I include it into the project:

in .angular-cli.json

```
...

"scripts": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
  ],

...
```

I have created an injection token in a separate file:

```
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';
import {IToastr} from './toastr.model';

export let TOASTR_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<IToastr>('toastr');
```

then in `app.module.ts` I include it as a provider:

```
import {TOASTR_TOKEN} from './common/tokens';

let toastr = window['toastr'];

...
providers: [
    ...
    {provide: TOASTR_TOKEN, useValue: toastr}
],
...
```

Comment: i dont think it will work like this check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) on how to include third party libs in Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some research I found a solution to my problem. What saved the day was exporting the variable which I use to assign to `useValue` property of the provider:

```
import {TOASTR_TOKEN} from './common/tokens';

export let toastr = window['toastr'];

...
providers: [
    ...
    {provide: TOASTR_TOKEN, useValue: toastr}
],
```

...